# How to subtract one column from another in a dynamic set of columns followed by multiplication of another column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has multiple columns. Out of which I need to pick up few columns, subtract one from the other, and then multiply the result with another column.

For demonstration, I have simulated a simple dataframe, but with a similar structure to my actual dataframe.

**Below is what I tried:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0':['09-June-2022', '10-June-2022', \
                           '11-June-2022', '12-June-2022'],
                    'col1':[1,-2,3,-4], 'col2':[-2,5,6,-8], \
                   'col3':[-5,-5,5,9], 'col4': [3,4,5,6]})

print(df)

columnlist = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

diff = 0
for c in columnlist:
    diff = diff - df[c]
    
final_calculation = diff.mul(df['col4'])
print(final_calculation)
```

**On printing the df, it looks like this:**

```
           col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  09-June-2022     1    -2    -5     3
1  10-June-2022    -2     5    -5     4
2  11-June-2022     3     6     5     5
3  12-June-2022    -4    -8     9     6
```

**The output that I get is:**

```
0    18
1     8
2   -70
3    18
```

**But it is incorrect. Ideally the final df should have been:**

```
0 24
1 -8
2 -15
3 -30
```

I'm unable to wrap my head around this. Tried df.sub, df.diff, tried using lambda, assign, somehow unable to figure it out completely. Please help!

My actual df looks something like below:

```
df_export_interchangedata:                GeneratedAt  CalculatedEmissionFactor   CPLE  CPLW    DUK    LGEE    MISO  NYIS   OVEC    TVA
0     2018-07-01 01:00:00                  0.000258  105.0   0.0  603.0  1133.0     0.0   0.0  578.0  621.0
1     2018-07-01 02:00:00                  0.000251    0.0   0.0  535.0   992.0     0.0   0.0  577.0  795.0
2     2018-07-01 03:00:00                  0.000246    2.0   0.0  123.0   897.0     0.0   0.0  545.0  801.0
3     2018-07-01 04:00:00                  0.000239  520.0   0.0    0.0   833.0     0.0   0.0  467.0  778.0
4     2018-07-01 05:00:00                  0.000233  596.0   0.0   18.0   679.0     0.0   0.0  343.0  637.0
...                   ...                       ...    ...   ...    ...     ...     ...   ...    ...    ...
60490 2022-05-30 20:00:00                       NaN  182.0   0.0    0.0   101.0  2555.0   0.0    NaN    0.0
60491 2022-05-30 21:00:00                       NaN  268.0   0.0    0.0   185.0  3555.0   0.0    NaN    0.0
60492 2022-05-30 22:00:00                       NaN   30.0   0.0    0.0   124.0  3681.0   0.0    NaN    0.0
60493 2022-05-30 23:00:00                       NaN    0.0   0.0    0.0   118.0  2846.0   0.0    NaN    0.0
60494 2022-05-31 00:00:00                       NaN    0.0   0.0    0.0     0.0  2098.0   0.0    NaN    0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is multiple all columns without first by `-1`, then sum and last multiple by `col4`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(columnlist[1:], -1)
d[columnlist[0]] = 1
print (d)
{'col2': -1, 'col3': -1, 'col1': 1}

df['out'] = df[columnlist].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1).sum(axis=1).mul(df['col4'])
print (df)
           col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  out
0  09-June-2022     1    -2    -5     3   24
1  10-June-2022    -2     5    -5     4   -8
2  11-June-2022     3     6     5     5  -40
3  12-June-2022    -4    -8     9     6  -30
```

EDIT:

```
df['out'] = df[columnlist].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1).sum(axis=1) 
print (df)
           col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  out
0  09-June-2022     1    -2    -5     3    8
1  10-June-2022    -2     5    -5     4   -2
2  11-June-2022     3     6     5     5   -8
3  12-June-2022    -4    -8     9     6   -5

df['out'] *= df['col4'].to_numpy()
print (df)
           col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  out
0  09-June-2022     1    -2    -5     3   24
1  10-June-2022    -2     5    -5     4   -8
2  11-June-2022     3     6     5     5  -40
3  12-June-2022    -4    -8     9     6  -30
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. When I apply it on my actual data frame, I get Array Memory Error.
```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 27.3 GiB for an array with shape (60495, 60495) and data type float64
```

Comment: @incrediblegiant -if use only  print(`df[columnlist].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1))` working with error?

Comment: Are you suggesting to remove the last mul for time being to see what happens? i.e. remove .mul(df['col4'])

Comment: @incrediblegiant - it is for testing only.

Comment: Okay, I get "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1" if I remove the second mul

Comment: @incrediblegiant - Can you test `print(df[columnlist].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1))` ?

Comment: Strange, I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mul'

Comment: @incrediblegiant - it seems `df` is overwriting, what is `print (df)` ?

Comment: I'm checking. Meanwhile, if it'd help, I'll print my actual df as an answer below because it doesn't let me print here

Comment: @incrediblegiant - In my opinion not necessary, error means `print (df[columnlist])` is `None`, so something wrong there

Comment: print(df) goes through without problems. Also print(df[columnlist]) also prints the values.

Comment: @incrediblegiant - and still error `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mul'` if use `print(df[columnlist].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1))` ?

Comment: Ah my bad. It does print with signs inverted which is what we want. So we're good.  Adding second mul throws memory error.

Comment: @incrediblegiant - very weird, can you test EDIT? I use multiple like another step, I hope working well.

Comment: I will test again and let know. Thanks so much.